# How do I use Google Analytics custom events inside my rails controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

What I want to do is use google analytic's custom event tracking from within my controllers, where the logic is done. I'm not quite sure how to put javascript code in my controller or if it is possible at all. How would I go about putting something like this inside my controller:

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
```

or

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);
```

thanks! And which one of these should I be using?
EDIT:

Here's how I set it up based on the suggestion:

tracking code partial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-ACCOUNT']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'sitename.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  <%= render "layouts/ga_events" %>

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

_ga_events.html.erb (I added in the "value" parameter)

```
<% unless session[:events].nil? %>
  <% session[:events].each do |event|%>
     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '<%= event[:category]%>', '<%= event[:action]%>', '<%= event[:label]%>', '<%= event[:value]%>']);
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% session[:events] = Array.new %>
```

application controller (added "value param)

```
  protected
    # GA event logger
    def log_event(category, action, label = nil, value = nil)
      session[:events] ||= Array.new
      session[:events] << {:category => category, :action => action, :label => label, :value => value}
    end
```

testing it in my Tasks controller:

```
def create
    @task = @user.tasks.build(params[:task])
    @task.author = current_user unless @user == current_user

    if @task.save
        log_event("Tasks", "Created", current_user.email, "123")
        redirect_back tasks_path, :notice => t('tasks.created')
    else
        redirect_back tasks_path, :alert => @task.errors.full_messages
    end
end
```

EDIT: here my GA output code, looks like everything is correct:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA_CODE']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'SUBDOMAIN']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
       _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Priority', 'Created (day)', 'Label info', '']);



  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's how I do it, it's quite similar to how RoR implements `flash`.  Essentially, on the server side you store up the events that you eventually want to push to GA via Javascript.  When a page is eventually rendered, you render Javascript to push the events, and reset your store.

So...

```
# application_controller.rb
protected
def log_event(category, action, label)
    session[:events] ||= Array.new
    session[:events] << {:category => category, :action => action, :label => label}
end
```

.. call that method from your individual controller methods as many times as you please.

```
# application.html.erb
<head>
... other stuff...
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<%= CONFIG['ga_account_id'] %>']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    <%= render "layouts/ga_events" %>
</script>
```

.. and the little partial referenced there is:

```
# _ga_events.html.erb
<% unless session[:events].nil? %>
  <% session[:events].each do |event|%>
     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '<%= event[:category]%>', '<%= event[:action]%>', '<%= event[:label]%>']);
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% session[:events] = Array.new %>
```

Comment: i'm trying this now...how do I confirm it works without waiting for GA to update the data? Also, does it matter that each account has its own subdomain? I would like to track all subdomains separately (I already setup advanced filters for this). Lastly, how does this work in the dev environment? Thanks!!

Comment: added the solution to the original post - would you mind looking if I have it correct?

Comment: I think the appropriate sanity check for "does this work" is to look at the generated HTML in your browser and see if you see the appropriate JS written in the HTML.  Compare that to the docs for GA.  You could also unit test for the appropriate JS in the HTML, using an rspec request test I suppose.  If this solution write the appropriate JS into the HTML, then from there it's more of a matter of "how do I test GA events", which I think is rather a different question.

Comment: I don't know anything about managing multiple sub-domains in a single GA account.  For my development environments, I typically set up a separate GA account, and push events there.  (That's why the GA account is a variable `CONFIG['ga_account_id']`.)  It doesn't help with the issue of waiting for GA to update the data, but at least your development events don't get muddled into your production data.

Comment: It looks like I set up everything properly, and the _trackEvent method is inside my GA code with all the proper variables...but nothing is showing up in GA for some reason. I thought maybe there's lag but it's been 10 hours.

Comment: Are you missing both pageviews and events in GA?  Or just events?

Comment: Just events. I sent an initial test event through earlier in the day (but I can't remember what method I used to do it). However, that event had a specific value "123" associated with it. All new events used nil (""), which I think may be causing the issue. I changed all of them to default to "0" rather than nil so we'll see if that works. (PS I copied the GA script output in my initial question...it looks correct)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7769/discussion-between-matthew-berman-and-cailinanne)

Comment: would you please enter the correct solution, your answer is really helpful but i am still having the issues which you discussed. please add the correct solution also

Answer (score 4):

Jumping onto this suuuuper late, but here's a really quick option to the above.  Just place this code in the controller that should trigger the custom event:

```
flash.now[:event] = "<script>_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '#{category}', '#{action}'])</script>".html_safe
```

Much shorter than using sessions!

Answer (score 1):

All of this is almost correct, but Google analytics **does not accept empty string, and the last parameter must be an integer**.

So I modified the **_ga_events.html.erb** like this:

```
<% unless session[:events].nil? %>
    <% session[:events].each do |event|%>
        <%params=[]%>
        <%params << "'_trackEvent'"%>
        <%params << "'#{event[:category] || "undefined" }'"%>
        <%params << "'#{event[:action] || "undefined" }'" %>
        <%params << "'#{event[:label]}'" if !event[:label].blank?%>
        <%params << event[:value].to_i if !event[:value].blank?%>
        _gaq.push([<%=params.join(', ')%>]);
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% session[:events] = Array.new %>
```

With this setting I get almost instant refresh of the tracked events in GA...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this great little gem that is called [Rack Tracker](https://github.com/railslove/rack-tracker). It allows you to attach a bunch of popular trackers (GA, GTM, FB Pixel, etc.) to it, and fire associated events through controllers like so:

```
def show
  tracker do |t|
    t.google_analytics :send, { type: 'event', category: 'button', action: 'click', label: 'nav-buttons', value: 'X' }
  end
end
```

which becomes:

```
ga('send', { 'hitType': 'event', 'eventCategory': 'button', 'eventAction': 'click', 'eventLabel': 'nav-buttons', 'value': 'X' })
```

OR you could use another gem - [Gabba](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gabba), which works in similar fashion:

```
Gabba::Gabba.new("UT-1234", "mydomain.com").page_view("something", "track/me")
```